# x11 forwarding with paramiko

Tags: python, x11, paramiko, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run a command with `paramiko` that should be able to open an X window. The script I'm using would something as follows:

```
import paramiko                                    

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect('192.168.122.55', username='user', password='password')
transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
session = transport.open_session()

session.request_x11()
stdin = session.makefile('wb')
stdout = session.makefile('rb')
stderr = session.makefile_stderr('rb')
session.exec_command('env; xterm')
transport.accept()

print 'Exit status:', session.recv_exit_status()
print 'stdout:\n{}'.format(stdout.read())
print 'stderr:\n{}'.format(stderr.read())
session.close()
```

Unfortunately, when I run the script above, I get this output:

```
Exit status: 1
stdout:
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=8025e1ba5e6c47be0d2f3ad6504a25ee-1347286654.617967-1932974971
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.122.1 58654 22
USER=user
MAIL=/var/mail/user
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PWD=/home/user
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/user
LOGNAME=user
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.122.1 58654 192.168.122.55 22
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
_=/usr/bin/env

stderr:  
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

If I run the following command in a terminal:

```
ssh -X user@192.168.122.55 'env; xterm'
```

then I get the same environment variables (some ports changed, though), so I'd say that my environment is correct. However, I'm still missing something to make `paramiko` work with x11 forwarding.

A couple of things I tried are:

- Use the `handler` parameter in `request_x11`: aside from printing values, I didn't get any further than with the default handler.
- Use the `auth_cookie` parameter in `request_x11`: tried to hardcode a cookie value that was being used according to the `xauth list` output. The idea of doing this was to avoid problems that might happen according to the documentation string in `paramiko` itself:

> If you omit the auth_cookie, a new secure random 128-bit value will be
>   generated, used, and returned.  You will need to use this value to
>   verify incoming x11 requests and replace them with the actual local
>   x11 cookie (which requires some knoweldge of the x11 protocol).

Is there some other thing I could do to make it work or troubleshoot the problem?

Note:
This has been previously asked in:

- [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/217420/117041): the only response points to the `request_x11` documentation I've already tried to use to no avail.
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4448089/183066): the accepted response suggests to use the `handler` parameter, but it's wrong.
- [github](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/40): no answer provided for more than a year.

Comment: With the paramico session active: (1) run `netstat -lpn` as root on the remote computer. Does it listen on port 6010, address 127.0.0.1? (2) What does `ls -l ~user/.Xauthority` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the `x11` request may use a `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` that you may not handled properly
- using ssh directly I saw it needed to confirm the x11 request (cookie challenge?)
- the `.Xauthority` file may also be an issue
- you can try to `strace` ssh process and see a normal flow
- in your script, you can replace `xterm` with `strace xterm` and compare with the above.

some links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization
- http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ssh/message/6747
- http://answers.tectia.com/questions/523/how-do-i-enable-x11-forwarding-for-users-without-a-home-directory

good luck.

EDIT: 
building **on top of** Gary's answer, with multiple x11 connections.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import select
import sys
import getpass
import paramiko
import socket
import logging
import Xlib.support.connect as xlib_connect
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# connection settings
host = '192.168.122.55'
user = 'user'
password = getpass.getpass()

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(host, username=user, password=password)
del password

# maintain map
# { fd: (channel, remote channel), ... }
channels = {}

poller = select.poll()
def x11_handler(channel, (src_addr, src_port)):
    '''handler for incoming x11 connections
    for each x11 incoming connection,
    - get a connection to the local display
    - maintain bidirectional map of remote x11 channel to local x11 channel
    - add the descriptors to the poller
    - queue the channel (use transport.accept())'''
    x11_chanfd = channel.fileno()
    local_x11_socket = xlib_connect.get_socket(*local_x11_display[:3])
    local_x11_socket_fileno = local_x11_socket.fileno()
    channels[x11_chanfd] = channel, local_x11_socket
    channels[local_x11_socket_fileno] = local_x11_socket, channel
    poller.register(x11_chanfd, select.POLLIN)
    poller.register(local_x11_socket, select.POLLIN)
    LOGGER.debug('x11 channel on: %s %s', src_addr, src_port)
    transport._queue_incoming_channel(channel)

def flush_out(session):
    while session.recv_ready():
        sys.stdout.write(session.recv(4096))
    while session.recv_stderr_ready():
        sys.stderr.write(session.recv_stderr(4096))

# get local disply
local_x11_display = xlib_connect.get_display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
# start x11 session
transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
session = transport.open_session()
session.request_x11(handler=x11_handler)
session.exec_command('xterm')
session_fileno = session.fileno()
poller.register(session_fileno, select.POLLIN)
# accept first remote x11 connection
transport.accept()

# event loop
while not session.exit_status_ready():
    poll = poller.poll()
    # accept subsequent x11 connections if any
    if len(transport.server_accepts) > 0:
        transport.accept()
    if not poll: # this should not happen, as we don't have a timeout.
        break
    for fd, event in poll:
        if fd == session_fileno:
            flush_out(session)
        # data either on local/remote x11 socket
        if fd in channels.keys():
            channel, counterpart = channels[fd]
            try:
                # forward data between local/remote x11 socket.
                data = channel.recv(4096)
                counterpart.sendall(data)
            except socket.error:
                channel.close()
                counterpart.close()
                del channels[fd]

print 'Exit status:', session.recv_exit_status()
flush_out(session)
session.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide the source of a minimal example that is working for you?

Comment: This is the answer that works for me. I still translate the example into real code, but I think it's going to be helpful thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Reading the paramiko code, I realized that paramiko only implements a way to establish an x11 channel. It does not connect the channel to the local x11 display. That is left to you.

Here is a small implementation that I have just written:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import select
import sys

import paramiko
import Xlib.support.connect as xlib_connect


local_x11_display = xlib_connect.get_display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
local_x11_socket = xlib_connect.get_socket(*local_x11_display[:3])


ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect('server', username='username', password='password')
transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
session = transport.open_session()
session.request_x11(single_connection=True)
session.exec_command('xterm')
x11_chan = transport.accept()

session_fileno = session.fileno()
x11_chan_fileno = x11_chan.fileno()
local_x11_socket_fileno = local_x11_socket.fileno()

poller = select.poll()
poller.register(session_fileno, select.POLLIN)
poller.register(x11_chan_fileno, select.POLLIN)
poller.register(local_x11_socket, select.POLLIN)
while not session.exit_status_ready():
    poll = poller.poll()
    if not poll: # this should not happen, as we don't have a timeout.
        break
    for fd, event in poll:
        if fd == session_fileno:
            while session.recv_ready():
                sys.stdout.write(session.recv(4096))
            while session.recv_stderr_ready():
                sys.stderr.write(session.recv_stderr(4096))
        if fd == x11_chan_fileno:
            local_x11_socket.sendall(x11_chan.recv(4096))
        if fd == local_x11_socket_fileno:
            x11_chan.send(local_x11_socket.recv(4096))

print 'Exit status:', session.recv_exit_status()
while session.recv_ready():
    sys.stdout.write(session.recv(4096))
while session.recv_stderr_ready():
    sys.stdout.write(session.recv_stderr(4096))
session.close()
```

Some notes:

- I'm using some helper functions from python-Xlib. This is a pure python implementation of Xlib. See this question for details on installing it: [How do you install Python Xlib with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054745/how-do-you-install-python-xlib-with-pip)
- Some of the details of how I have implemented this make me believe it will only work for 1 x11 connection (hence `session.request_x11(single_connection=True)`.) I would like to keep working at this to get it to handle multiple connections, but that will have to wait for another day.
- This code essentially connects the following channels/sockets together in a async fashion using [`select.poll`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html):

  - `session.stdout` -> `sys.stdout`
  - `session.stderr` -> `sys.stderr`
  - `x11channel` -> `local_x11_socket`
  - `local_x11_socket` - > `x11channel`
- The `paramiko` module outputs alot of usefull debuging info to the `logging` module. You can view this by configuring the logging module:

  ```
  import logging
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been looking at your example; but, despite is promising, doesn't seem to work for other commands I tried. For example, if I try `gnome-terminal` I get `Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.` and if I try `firefox`, I get `Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0`.

Comment: The other two answers claim to be based on yours, so it's fair that you get the bounty. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you all for the piece of code. I just have two comments, first python-xlib `get_socket` function take 4 parameters in version 0.26 so the call should be `xlib_connect.get_socket(*local_x11_display[:4])`. I also had an `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError` during the X11 handshaking so I had to open the access with `xhost +` which is normally not necessary with `ssh -X`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you asked for a *minimal* version, which I understand as make it as easy to to use as possible.  Here is a version based in both codes, but this separate the x11 session commands from the general code, making the main program simple and the session code reusable:

```
import paramiko
import os
import select
import sys
import Xlib.support.connect as xlib_connect

def run(transport, session, command):
    def x11_handler(channel, (src_addr, src_port)):
        x11_fileno = channel.fileno()
        local_x11_channel = xlib_connect.get_socket(*local_x11_display[:3])
        local_x11_fileno = local_x11_channel.fileno()

        # Register both x11 and local_x11 channels
        channels[x11_fileno] = channel, local_x11_channel
        channels[local_x11_fileno] = local_x11_channel, channel

        poller.register(x11_fileno, select.POLLIN)
        poller.register(local_x11_fileno, select.POLLIN)

        transport._queue_incoming_channel(channel)

    def flush_out(channel):
        while channel.recv_ready():
            sys.stdout.write(channel.recv(4096))
        while channel.recv_stderr_ready():
            sys.stderr.write(channel.recv_stderr(4096))

    local_x11_display = xlib_connect.get_display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])

    channels = {}
    poller = select.poll()
    session_fileno = session.fileno()
    poller.register(session_fileno)

    session.request_x11(handler=x11_handler)
    session.exec_command(command)
    transport.accept()

    # event loop
    while not session.exit_status_ready():
        poll = poller.poll()
        if not poll: # this should not happen, as we don't have a timeout.
            break
        for fd, event in poll:
            if fd == session_fileno:
                flush_out(session)
            # data either on local/remote x11 channels/sockets
            if fd in channels.keys():
                sender, receiver = channels[fd]
                try:
                    receiver.sendall(sender.recv(4096))
                except:
                    sender.close()
                    receiver.close()
                    channels.remove(fd)

    flush_out(session)
    return session.recv_exit_status()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect('192.168.122.55', username='user', password='password')
    transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
    session = transport.open_session()
    run(transport, session, 'xterm')
```

I know you could do it by yourself.  However, but just by copying the function `run` anybody could use it without hassle.

The right answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903844/278878.  This example is to make it easier for newcomers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Have you tried some other commands aside from `xterm`? I've tried `gnome-terminal` and `firefox` and both seem wait forever (in no particular location according to the traceback I get when prissing `Ctrl`+`C`).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks  **Gary van der Merwe** and **dnozay** for their code. The code below heavily relies on it and serves for running X programs on Windows. The notable difference is using select.select instead of poll, as poll is not available in Windows. Any improvements or corrections are welcome.

```
import select
import sys
import paramiko
import Xlib.support.connect as xlib_connect
import os
import socket
import subprocess



# run xming
XmingProc = subprocess.Popen("C:/Program Files (x86)/Xming/Xming.exe :0 -clipboard -multiwindow")
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(SSHServerIP, SSHServerPort, username=user, password=pwd)
transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
channelOppositeEdges = {}

local_x11_display = xlib_connect.get_display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
inputSockets = []

def x11_handler(channel, (src_addr, src_port)):
    local_x11_socket = xlib_connect.get_socket(*local_x11_display[:3])
    inputSockets.append(local_x11_socket)
    inputSockets.append(channel)
    channelOppositeEdges[local_x11_socket.fileno()] = channel
    channelOppositeEdges[channel.fileno()] = local_x11_socket
    transport._queue_incoming_channel(channel)

session = transport.open_session()
inputSockets.append(session)
session.request_x11(handler = x11_handler)
session.exec_command('xterm')
transport.accept()

while not session.exit_status_ready():
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputSockets,[],[])
    if len(transport.server_accepts) > 0:
        transport.accept()
    for sock in readable:
        if sock is session:
            while session.recv_ready():
                sys.stdout.write(session.recv(4096))
            while session.recv_stderr_ready():
                sys.stderr.write(session.recv_stderr(4096))   
        else: 
            try:
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                counterPartSocket  = channelOppositeEdges[sock.fileno()]
                counterPartSocket.sendall(data)
            except socket.error:
                inputSockets.remove(sock)
                inputSockets.remove(counterPartSocket)
                del channelOppositeEdges[sock.fileno()]
                del channelOppositeEdges[counterPartSocket.fileno()]
                sock.close()
                counterPartSocket.close()

print 'Exit status:', session.recv_exit_status()
while session.recv_ready():
    sys.stdout.write(session.recv(4096))
while session.recv_stderr_ready():
    sys.stdout.write(session.recv_stderr(4096))
session.close()
XmingProc.terminate()
XmingProc.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

For those working in Mac OS X Leopard, there is no select.poll(). Here is a modified version of [dnozay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876252/1824948) using kqueue instead of poll. Any improvements/corrections on this would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import select
import sys
import paramiko
import socket
import Xlib.support.connect as xlib_connect

# get local display
local_x11_display = xlib_connect.get_display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect('hostname', port=22, username='username', password='password')

channels = {}
kq = select.kqueue()

def x11Handler(x11_chan, (src_addr, src_port)):
    x11_chan_fileno = x11_chan.fileno()
    local_x11_socket = xlib_connect.get_socket(*local_x11_display[:3])
    local_x11_socket_fileno = local_x11_socket.fileno()
    channels[x11_chan_fileno] = x11_chan, local_x11_socket
    channels[local_x11_socket_fileno] = local_x11_socket, x11_chan

    ev = [select.kevent(x11_chan_fileno, filter=select.KQ_FILTER_READ, flags=select.KQ_EV_ADD), select.kevent(local_x11_socket_fileno, filter=select.KQ_FILTER_READ, flags=select.KQ_EV_ADD)]
    kevents = kq.control(ev, 0, None)
    transport._queue_incoming_channel(x11_chan)

def flushOut(session):
    while session.recv_ready():
        sys.stdout.write(session.recv(4096))
    while session.recv_stderr_ready():
        sys.stderr.write(session.recv_stderr(4096))

# start x11 session
transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
session = transport.open_session()
session.request_x11(handler=x11Handler)
session.exec_command('xterm')

# accept first remote x11 connection
x11_chan = transport.accept()
session_fileno = session.fileno()

session_ev = [select.kevent(session_fileno, 
    filter=select.KQ_FILTER_READ,
    flags=select.KQ_EV_ADD)] 

kevents_session = kq.control(session_ev, 0, None)

# event loop
while not session.exit_status_ready():
    r_events = kq.control(None, 4)
    # accept subsequent x11 connections if any

    if len(transport.server_accepts) > 0:
        transport.accept()
    if not r_events: # this should not happen, as we don't have a timeout.
        break
    for event in r_events:
        print event
        if event.ident & session_fileno:
            flushOut(session)
        # data either on local/remote x11 socket
        if event.ident in channels.keys():
            x11_chan, counterpart = channels[event.ident]
            try:
                # forward data between local/remote x11 socket.
                data = x11_chan.recv(4096)
                counterpart.sendall(data)
            except socket.error:
                x11_chan.close()
                counterpart.close()
                del channels[event.ident]

flushOut(session)
kq.close()
session.close()
```